# Draggable editable field

Tags: javascript, html, css, textfield

I want to have an editable field that I can drag and drop. Here is my code (the red div is the drop zone) :

```js
function drag(ev) {
  let targetId = ev.target.id;
  let rect = document.getElementById(targetId).getBoundingClientRect();
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("targetId", targetId);
  let offsetX = ev.clientX - rect.left;
  let offsetY = ev.clientY - rect.top;
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("offsetX", offsetX);
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("offsetY", offsetY);
}

function drop(ev) {
  let targetId = ev.dataTransfer.getData("targetId");
  let offsetX = parseInt(ev.dataTransfer.getData("offsetX"));
  let offsetY = parseInt(ev.dataTransfer.getData("offsetY"));
  let dropX = ev.clientX - offsetX;
  let dropY = ev.clientY - offsetY;
  let el = document.getElementById(targetId);
  el.style.left = dropX + "px";
  el.style.top = dropY + "px";
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.item {
  min-width: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  border: solid;
  background: white;
}

#item1 {
  padding: 3px;
}

#drop-zone {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="drop-zone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br> 
<span class="item" contenteditable="true" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">Item1</span> 
<br><br>
<div id="item1" class="item" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
  <span contenteditable="true">Item2</span>
</div>
```

I made 2 tests. My first test is `Item1`, where the `<span>` itself is draggable. Unfortunately, the browser cannot differenciate between "place the cursor" and "drag the element", so `Item1` is not draggable.

Then my idea was to have a border around the field on which we would click to grab the element, so I made `Item2` where I put the `<span>` in a containing `<div>`. But now the problem is that, as the div is draggable, the span also is draggable, but I want to place the cursor freely in the span, and when I click on the span to write some text, the cursor is always at the beginning. How should I do ?

Note : when I remove the `padding: 3px` line, `Item2` doesn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could always use Jquery draggable, I used it for more or less the same reason as what you are asking for and it worked wonders.

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

Comment: @KallenNewick That's a very good feature but I still cannot put the cursor where I want. When I click on the span, the cursor is always at the beginning.

Comment: I ran the snippet, and and the cursor was placed correctly every time I tapped the span, not sure if this is something browser specific

Comment: On `Span1` this is normal, but the drawback is that it cannot be dragged. With `Span2` on the other hand, it can be dragged but the cursor cannot be put freely. I'm on Firefox developer. EDIT: It works on Chrome but the dragging is not smooth.